# Noise caused by the separate power supply of the sensor?

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi, proximity-sensor, ground-loop

For my experiment I built a circuit to record long-term vibration data. It consists of two types of sensors (proximity revolution and MEMS acceleration), Arduino, Raspberry Pi and power supplies, which are connected together as shown in the schematic.

[image]

The problem is that I have too much noise in my acceleration signal (see the spikes at the bottom). I suppose it is a ground loop problem. Does anyone have an idea what it actually could be?

[image]

Comment: In order to talk about ground loop problems, details about the physical wiring might be helpful. Just knowing that the schematic bonds all grounds together is probably not enough for a comprehensive answer.

Comment: _"Noise caused by the **separate** power supply of the sensor?"_ - According your diagram the sensor _doesn't_ have a separate power supply, it is powered by the Arduino that it is connected to (which is powered from the Pi). So how much noise can you see on the Arduino's 3.3V output? I notice that your plot shows much lower noise for the first 0.1 second or so. What's going on there? Please provide a photo of the setup showing all wiring.

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have that setup. I did the measurement 3 months ago, but I only had time to see the measurement data recently. I can definitely recreate the situation. However I had another measurement without rotation sensor, which was ok.

Comment: What are the output levels of the RPM sensor? Can you rule out for sure that those spikes are not from another (external) source? E.g. speech?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely EMI is from DCDC common mode leakage and unbalanced sensors.  But a complete physical layout is critical.
With cable types.

To remedy CMRR connect Line gnd to 0V or use a cap for AC noise interfering with nyquist bandstop inside 2axis Accel.  Even though this defeats the opto isolation, it should still work.  You could run the RPM opto from 3.3V with the series R reduced for same current and try different GNd caps to Earth Gnd to block 50Hz but shunt RF and DCDc leakage noise.

Then add LC filters or Rc filter to 3V3 to mitigate if noise exists and make noise <100uV into AC coupled 50 ohm scope terminated.

if it still exists use gnd shielding. Or CM choke to sensor LLC filter.

It would help if you defined all nearby noise generators.  Your noise could be above sampling rate or below with a thousand spikes in 30e6 samples.

I presume RPM is ok. Even though 24V is overkill for a 1.2V IR diode

Answer (score 0):

> I suppose it is a ground loop problem.

I see evidence in the acceleration data graph you supplied, which does not agree with a random analog cause like that.

> Does anyone have an idea what it actually could be?

You need to investigate the digital values from your accelerometer, and the subsequent calculations you are performing using those values.

Looking at the graph you supplied, for all the "low spikes", **the value always drops to one of only two numbers** - the "low spikes" have no other values. I have drawn them as 2 red lines here, on part of your graph:

[image: Part of acceleration graph, with the 2 lowest numbers shown as red lines across multiple points]

That would not happen with random analog noise.

We have seen previous questions with spurious acceleration values, where again the spurious values were not random. In each case, the cause was found to be something like incorrect reading of the accelerometer registers, or incorrect calculations from those register contents e.g. leading to overflow in 16-bit calculations and hence incorrectly showing very low values, just like on your graph.